# Javascript macro to find image

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

Current code i have is:

```
function(){
var eventCat = "";
if({{element}}.children[0].tagName == "img") {
    eventCat = "Image";
}
return eventCat;
}
```

However, this is not appending "Image" to the event Category. Can someone check my code?

Comment: can you share the site?

Comment: Can you add additional information regarding the event tag and rules, and what I would need to do to recreate the issue?

Comment: Simple custom javascript macro for {{image links}} using the above function. Rule set to fire on the event tag when event contains gtm.linkClick and {{Image Links}} contains Image. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

When I click a link on your site, say for example the *Last Minute* navigation, I see a gtm.click event fire, but not a gtm.linkClick event fire.

[image]

This tells me that your linkClick event listener propbably isn't setup correctly. Could you provide me some screenshots on your configurations for your linkClick tag, event tag for the images?

Comment: i rolled back to a previous container last night so i think thats what you are seeing, i can share a preview with you for the current testing container, can you pass your email?